# Determinants and Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For every square matrix, there is one and only one determinant associated with the matrix.

Can you explain how this statement illustrates the concept of a function?

Comment: For a function, every input (x) has one output (y). So in case of matrices, every square matrix (input) has one output (determinant). It doesn't go the other way around, that is, for every value of determinant there is one corresponding square matrix, because you can have many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important detail of a function is that it maps each value in the domain to exactly one output value. This is why we have the vertical line test from grade school - it's a way of saying that each $x$ value only corresponds to one $y = f(x)$ value.

In this case, the determinant is a function that takes in a matrix and outputs a real number. Since there's only one determinant for each matrix, it's a valid or well defined function.

Answer (score 1):

A [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a relation that for every element in its domain yields exactly one output.

In your example, if we consider the set of square matrices as the domain, for each element in the domain (i.e. for every square matrix) a scalar is output (the determinant). Hence, the determinant is a well-defined function.